# Find xy coordinates of a point knowing its distance to other 2 points

Tags: r, geometry, trigonometry, triangulation, mds

I'm writing a code in R to calculate the xy coordinates of point, using the law of cosines.
I have two reference points (1 and 2) which the xy coordinates are known. I want to find the coordinates of the other point (3). I know the distances 3-1, 3-2 and 1-2, but I don't know the angles between them.

Thanks in advance for any help!

I've tried some trigonometric equations I've found on web and Rohlf&Archie 1978 paper, but they don't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your data to make the question reproducible [MRE]. And include the code you have tried so that the programming problem can be clearly set out. This helps others help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told us your set-up exactly, but it sounds as though you have two known x, y, co-ordinates:

```r
x1 <- 1
x2 <- 5

y1 <- 3
y2 <- 6
```

And known distances between these two points plus a third point:

```
d12 <- 5
d13 <- 8
d23 <- 5
```

We can draw them like this:

```r
plot(c(x1, x2), c(y1, y2), xlim = c(0, 12), ylim = c(0, 12))
text(c(x1, x2), c(y1, y2) + 0.5, labels = c('1', '2'))
```

[image]

Now, it's obviously easy to calculate the angle between the horizontal line and the segment joining points 1 and two - it's just the arctangent of the slope:

```r
abline(h = y1, lty = 2)
theta <- atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)

segments(x1, y1, x1 + d12 * cos(theta), y1 + d12 * sin(theta), lty = 2)
```

[image]

Now, although we don't know where point 3 is, we can use the law of cosines to calculate the angle 3-1-2 like this:

```r
angle_312 <- acos((d12^2 + d13^2 - d23^2)/(2 * d12 * d13))
```

To get this in terms of angle from the horizontal we can do:

```r
angle_13 <- angle_312 - theta
```

This allows us to work out the co-ordinates of point 3:

```r
x3 <- x1 + d13 * cos(angle_13)
y3 <- y1 + d13 * sin(angle_13)
```

We can draw this point on our plot as follows:

```r
points(x3, y3)
text(x3, y3 + 0.5, '3')
```

[image]

And we can show that it is correct by drawing circles of the correct radius around points one and two. Point 3 should be at the meeting point of the two circles:

```r
polygon(x1 + dist_1_3 * cos(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 100)), 
        y1 + dist_1_3 * sin(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 100)), lty = 2)
polygon(x2 + dist_2_3 * cos(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 100)), 
        y2 + dist_2_3 * sin(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 100)), lty = 2)
```

[image]

Note that there is a second solution at the other point where the circles meet: in this case we would get that by changing `angle_13 <- angle_312 - theta` to `angle_13 <- angle_312 + theta`:

```r
angle_13 <- angle_312 + theta

x3 <- x1 + d13 * cos(angle_13)
y3 <- y1 + d13 * sin(angle_13)

points(x3, y3)
text(x3, y3 + 0.5, '3')
```

[image]

Comment: It should be the solution presented by Rohlf & Archie 1978. I think there is typo mistakes in the paper. As it is an ecology paper, nobody has realized it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we are using the following conditions:

```
pointA <- c(x1 = 1, y1 = 1)
pointC <- c(x2 = 4, y2 = 1)

AC <- sqrt(
  (pointA[["x1"]] - pointC[["x2"]])^2 +
  (pointA[["y1"]] - pointC[["y2"]])^2
)

AB <- 4

BC <- 5
```

We are looking for coordinates of point B (points B1 and B2) (`x3` and `y3` / `x3'` and `y3'`).

[image]

First we find `cos` and `sin` of angle C (ACB1 == ACB2 as CB1==CB2==a; AB1==AB2==c and AC=b is common):

```
cosC <-(AC^2 + BC^2 - AB^2) / (2*AC*BC)
sinC <- sqrt(1-cosC^2)
```

It is obvious that there are two possible solutions for the conditions.
Then the points will be

```
pointB1 <- c(x3 = pointC[["x2"]] + BC*cosC,
             y3 = pointC[["y2"]] + BC*sinC)

pointB2 <- c(x3 = pointC[["x2"]] - BC*cosC,
             y3 = pointC[["y2"]] - BC*sinC)
```

Now we can check the results:

```
> sqrt(
+   (pointB1[["x3"]] - pointC[["x2"]])^2 +
+     (pointB1[["y3"]] - pointC[["y2"]])^2
+ )
[1] 5
> sqrt(
+   (pointB2[["x3"]] - pointC[["x2"]])^2 +
+     (pointB2[["y3"]] - pointC[["y2"]])^2
+ )
[1] 5
```

The advantage of this solution that we do not call low precision `acos`function as well as other trigonometric functions. And use `cosC` / `sinC` as temporary variables only.